# How to make an object follow the mouse

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello I am having issues at making my object move onto the mouse position. Tried as below but the object moves into wrong direction.
It's an UI image item not sprite.

```
Vector3 m_mouse_pos;
m_mouse_pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
m_mouse_pos.z = Camera.main.nearClipPlane;
transform.localPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(m_mouse_pos);
```

How this could be done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement IDragHandler interface with IBeginDragHandlerand IEndDragHandler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think the problem was with the Rect Transform.